# Pattern Matching in R

Tags: r

I have a list like

```
> list(c("a","b","c","d"),c("b","c","e"))
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

[[2]]
[1] "b" "c" "e"
```

I have a sequence "bc". I want to match this pattern with my list and want to know the frequency of this pattern.
Required Output: 2
First of all, I need to convert my list into this format `c("abcd"),c("bce")` so that I can do matching. How to convert and match?
Second, how to calculate and store the frequency?

I was using grepl function but it returns logical value, not the count.

Comment: Could you provide the list in a way that is easily copied so we don't have to reconstruct it?

Comment: list(c("a","b","c","d"),c("b","c","e"))

Comment: @user2560936 that should go in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @Tyler's sample data, you can use `gregexpr`:

```
lst <- list(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'c'),
            c('b', 'c', 'e'))
lst2 <- lapply(lst, paste, collapse="")
sapply(gregexpr("bc", lst2, fixed = TRUE), length)
# [1] 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using `term.count` (a non exported function) from the qdap package:

```
lst <- list(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'c'),c('b', 'c', 'e'))
lst2 <- lapply(lst, paste, collapse="") #use lapply to paste the list

## install.packages("qdap")
sapply(lst2, qdap:::term.count, "bc") #count occurences

## > sapply(lst2, qdap:::term.count, "bc")
## bc bc 
##  2  1
```

If you don't want to use qdap look at the source for [term.count](https://github.com/trinker/qdap/blob/master/R/term.count.R) and take what you need.

Comment: I installed qdap package but while loading it is showing this error:
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry

Comment: Not sure exactly but it may have to do with the version of java you're using.  When I googled your error I got [this blog post](http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/) about it. You can figure that out or just cut and paste the code from the link to `term.count` I gave above and run it.

Comment: I want to store this count 2 in some variable for algebraic calculations. How can I do that?

Comment: Assign it to something with the `<-` operator??  Otherwise I don't know what you're asking.  I think you might need to read some of the R [introductory manuals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html)